# Orient text in cell to vertical with XlsxWriter?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I see a couple examples of how to set the orientation of a text box, but not cell in a text box. I see how to format other things, like **bold**:

```
bold_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
worksheet.write('A1', "something", bold_format)
```

but not vertically oriented text.

Comment: You talking about this? https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#set_rotation

Comment: @Scratch'n'Purr: Yes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use set_rotation.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("test.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.set_landscape()

bold_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
bold_format.set_rotation(90)

worksheet.write('A1', "something", bold_format)

workbook.close()
```

For the entire documentation on `set_rotation()` visit: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#format-set-rotation

Comment: You can also just put `'rotation': 90` in the format dictionary